# What font/style is being used in the following image

Tags: font-identification, font-size, paint.net

I'm customizing the design of a Shopify store and one of the templates uses this image as a logo:

[image]

How could I write a word using that same style and font with Paint.NET?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font is [Lombriz](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/sudtipos/lombriz/regular/). Someone who know Paint.NET can answer as regards the styling.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this awesome tool to upload it and find out!
http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont

If that image is transparent, as it appears to be, you might have to put a black background behind the text and resave so there is more contrast for the tool to figure it out.

Style is a gradient drop-shadow and white text color.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not the same font, I've recreated the image as best I could, using Paint.NET

[image]

The process is as follows:

1. Create a new layer & choose `black`.
2. Type your text using the text tool, be sure to pick the proper font, size & style
3. Duplicate this layer and choose **Adjustments > Invert Colors**.
4. Choose your first layer of text and then the **Move Tool.**
5. Using your arrow keys, press `right arrow` twice & `down arrow` twice to get the offset shadow look.
6. Now, choose **Adjustments > Hue/Saturation**
7. In this menu, slide the **Lightness** slider to the right until you get the gray color that you're looking for. *(Around `50`)*
8. Next, choose **Effects > Blurs > Gaussian Blur...**
9. In this menu, choose the appropriate amount of blur *(most likely only `2`)*
10. For the fade at the top, add a new layer to the very top of your **Layers** window.
11. Choose the **Rectangle Select** tool and draw a box spanning the full width of the layer and down to just below the half way point of the text.
12. Next, fill this selection with `White` by choosing the **Paint Bucket** tool and clicking within the selection.
13. Deselect your new white box by choosing one of the selection tools and clicking anywhere
14. Again, choose **Effects > Blurs > Gaussian Blur...**
15. This time, choose a large amount of blur *(around `90`)*

Congrats, you've now got your logo!